# memcpy from unsigned char * to unsigned int

Tags: c++, memcpy, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

I am not sure what the following C++ code does (I have replaced parts that don't matter with dots):

```
unsigned char* p = ...;
unsigned int metaNum;
memcpy( &metaNum, p, sizeof( unsigned int ) );
p += sizeof( unsigned int );

for ( unsigned int m = 0; m < metaNum; m++ ) {

...

}
```

I know for `memcpy` that:

> The underlying type of the objects pointed to by both the source and
>   destination pointers are irrelevant for this function; The result is a
>   binary copy of the data.

Still I am not sure what is the interpretation of `metaNum`. Is it something obvious or it has to do with the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not implementation-specific: `metaNum` is interpreted as a sequence of `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes, into which the content from the same number of bytes pointed to by `p` is copied.

The only thing in play here is [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness): the same sequence of bytes copied into `metaNum` will be interpreted differently depending on how the hardware is storing multi-byte values, such as `unsigned int`. If the sequence comes from the same hardware, interpretation would be the same. Otherwise, you would need to use [`ntoh`/`hton`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21996794/335858) functions to bring byte sequences into proper order.